# Site throws 403 Forbidden when opened from Cordova App in IOS 8.4.1

Tags: ios, .net, cordova, http-status-code-403, ios8.4

My Cordova app got rejected by AppStore review. The reason behind rejection is app exhibits bugs. Details of the affected functionality is furnished below.

My app has a **New User? Register here** link to the apps site, say **https://www.example.com**. When the user taps on the **example.com** opens in new safari window. It works fine for me. But AppStore team has attached a 403 screenshot in resolution center.

**The site doesn't throw 403 when accessed from any browser directly. Even from IOS Safari.**

Code to open the link is pasted below,

```
var ref = window.open('https://www.example.com', '_system', 'location=yes');
```

Not sure whether is a problem with the 8.4.1, Cordova or .net website.

Any kind of help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that your website is configured correctly? 403 means that they're unauthorized to get the page...

Comment: @lifeisfoo, yes, i can access the site properly via any browser, even from ios safari.

Comment: Your website require any authentication? Have you tried with a different or "clean" device?

Comment: @lifeisfoo, I can access the site properly from iphone safari. Is it something related  to the `https`

Comment: You should provide more information about the error and your webserver/site/webapp, otherwise I can't figure out how to solve this.

Comment: can you share the url? so we can try to access it and let you know if we can access or we get the 403

Comment: @jcesarmobile, `https://www.trialsapp.com/`

Comment: I tried to register and seems to work on my iPad with 8.4.1. The screenshot they send is from safari?

Comment: @jcesarmobile, yes, they shared safari's screenshot.

Comment: No idea then, but the problem must be on the server as the screenshot is from safari

Comment: @jcesarmobile, Yes it seems. Thanks for your time. :)